# Angularjs: OnsenUI: ng-disabled not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to disable a button based on an angular object array being empty. My HTML below..

```
<ons-button ng-click="do stuff" ng-disabled="testFunc()">Add</ons-button>
```

This is inside an ng-app HTML and inside of a controller.  My test function is below...

```
$scope.objs = [];
$scope.testFunc = function() {
    if($scope.objs == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

I have my function and the `$scope.objs = [];` declared inside the controller, and the button is not being disabled.  Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Appears the function is not even firing, will ng-disabled not fire once DOM is loaded.  Also, could there be an issue with declaring the array and maybe it wasnt declared intime for the function to test it?  Should I add an OR testing if its `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.objs` is an array, which is different than `null`. Try to check its `length` instead...

```
if($scope.objs.length === 0) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: okay, i can try that, i put a console.log in both if and else and nothing is logging, almost like the testFunc isnt even firing?  will it not auto fire once the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Just noticed the ng-disabled is on a custom directive. I don't think it'll work.